# Change these 2 queries to single query?

Tags: mysql

I want data and total in single query:

```
SELECT id, order_name, order_ownurl, order_category, order_id
FROM `order_details`
WHERE ordered_name='nikon d3200'
ORDER BY ordered_price asc
```

and

```
SELECT count(distinct order_id)
FROM `order_details`
WHERE ordered_name='nikon d3200'
```

Comment: one is raw data and the other is aggregation. Can you give an example of your data and how you want to display the result?

Comment: I need row and aggregation in single result

Comment: Is this not working???

SELECT id, order_name, order_ownurl , order_category, order_id, (SELECT  count(distinct order_id)  FROM `order_details` WHERE ordered_name='nikon d3200') FROM `products_details` WHERE ordered_name='nikon d3200' ORDER BY ordered_price asc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much much better way to do this, **why do we need subquery**?

Here is the solution, Please let me know if I m missing something!!

```
SELECT id, order_name, order_ownurl, order_category, order_id,count(distinct order_id)
FROM `order_details`
WHERE ordered_name='nikon d3200'
ORDER BY ordered_price asc
```

Explanation: As we are selecting data from a single table we don't need a subquery.
Subqueries look bad, we should use if nothing else works.

Please let me know if u face some problem.

Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can get the `COUNT` using a correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
  o1.id, 
  o1.order_name, 
  o1.order_ownurl, 
  o1.order_category, 
  o1.order_id,
  (SELECT count(distinct o2.order_id)
   FROM `order_details` o2
   WHERE o2.ordered_name = o1.ordered_name) AS OrderCount
FROM `order_details` o1
WHERE o1.ordered_name = 'nikon d3200'
ORDER BY o1.ordered_price asc;
```

Comment: @Malai Sorry didn't see this, I updated my answer. See my edit.